NodeJs/Flutter credit cards management app: Fetch and Display current user's cards
In the home page of mobile payment app, I want to display the current user's cards so they could choose with which card they wish to pay. So far, I predefined the list of asset images to populate the carousel, a momentary solution, but now I want the app to fetch the cards related to the specific userId of the current user. I want it to not only display the card's image withing the carousel, but also contain the card's data in order to later pass the selected card's data to the payment checkout. (PS: card selection happens simply by sliding across the available cards and tapping on the one you chose).
This is the UI relevant code with predefined assetImages:
Imports
.
.
.
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List cardAssetImagesPaths = ["assets/citiRewardsPlus.png","assets/CARTE_VISA_PLATINUM.png"];

  int _currentPage = 0;

  .
  .
  .

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      .
      .
      .


                SizedBox(
                  child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                    itemCount: cardAssetImagesPaths.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: _showBottomSheet,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage(
                                cardAssetImagesPaths[
                                    index % cardAssetImagesPaths.length],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                      height: 255.0,
                      viewportFraction: 0.85,
                      initialPage: 0,
                      enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                      enlargeCenterPage: true,
                      onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                        setState(() {
                          _currentPage = index;
                        });
                      },
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: List.generate(
                        cardAssetImagesPaths.length,
                        (index) => _buildDot(index),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .
                .
                .
                
  Widget _buildDot(int index) {
    return Container(
      width: 7.5,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: _currentPage == index
            ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 120, 202)
            : Color.fromARGB(255, 223, 223, 223),
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is my getUserCardData controller:
exports.getUserCardData = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const {userId} = req.body;

        let card = await CardService.getCarddata(userId);

        res.json({status:true,success:card})
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};
static async getCarddata(userId) {
        try {
            const cardData = await CardModel.find({ userId });
            return cardData;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }

This is an example of my getCarddata JSON response:
{
    "status": true,
    "success": [
        {
            "_id": "6612623962367a3003919463",
            "userId": "661261f462367a300391945f",
            "bankName": "Citi Bank",
            "cardName": "Rewards Plus",
            "cardNumber": "4000   0000   0000   0000",
            "expiryDate": "00/00",
            "cardHolderName": "Linda Walker",
            "cvvCode": "000",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "6350961962367a3003919463",
            "userId": "6350961962367a3003919463",
            "bankName": "HSBC",
            "cardName": "Oxygen Credit",
            "cardNumber": "4000   4000   4000   4000",
            "expiryDate": "00/00",
            "cardHolderName": "Linda Walker",
            "cvvCode": "000",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}

snapshot of my UI page
I understand I should add cardImage to cards.model but I need assistance with the cards images router and all relevant things etc...
Ps: I have added all possible credit cards images as png in a "images" file in the server directory
And I don't mind changing from the slider carousel package to pageView or anything else as long as the final result works, I can compromise user experience for functionality.
